# Unable to import modules into python 3

Tags: python, anaconda

Hello I am trying to learn python from the beginning and I keep running into an issue when importing modules. I am running python 3.6.4 and it was installed via anaconda 4.4.10. Here is an example of my issue: If I go to cmd line and run 'pip install requests' I get 'requirements already satisfied' Yet if I try to run this simple section of code in spyder:

```
 import requests from bs4
 import BeautifulSoup
 import operator

 def:
     word_list
```

I get an error on the first line right after the from, saying invalid syntax.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Also Sorry for any violations this is my first post!

Comment: Did you try [Googling `python import from`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+import+from) and looking at examples?

Comment: Thank, I didn't realize it went package then module. Marked as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have the `from`-`import` syntax wrong. It's not `import MODULE from PACKAGE`, it's `from PACKAGE import MODULE`.

Second, `requests` isn't in `bs4`; `BeautifulSoup` is.

Finally, your `def` is illegal because is has neither a name nor a parameter list.

To fix all of these problems:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def spam():
    word_list
```

Of course you'll still get an error when you call `spam`, because that `word_list` is never assigned a value anywhere, but you're trying to use its value. But you can solve that one when you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing your module wrong.

You have to first name the module you want to import something from in your case `requests` then what you specifically want to import `bs4`

`from requests import bs4`

furthermore, you should name your function.

edit:

apparently, `bs4` is also not a class in `requests`, you should probably look into a tutorial for python.